# Unexpected Gson object names

Tags: java, android, json, object, gson

I already have some API and cannot change any parameters and object names into.

One of them is it:

```
{  
   "version":"1.0",
   "error_code":"0",
   "error_message":"OK",
   "session_id":"2f0513adszdab61a4748553c62019a",
   "expire":"2014-12-13 17:38:13",
   "currencyData":{  
      "rate":"1",
      "position":"1",
      "ch":"dollar"
   },
   "data":{  
      "user_id":129733,
      "account_type":0
   },
   "new":{  
      "messages_count":0,
      "purchases_count":0,
      "sales_count":0,
      "offers_count":0,
      "orders_count":0,
      "cart_count":9
   }
}
```

In this responce i have objects "currencyData", "data" and "new". 
Right now i have troubles with this names after Deserialization, they are null.
My code for getting this recult is:

```
ApiResponse<UserData> response = new Gson().fromJson(json, UserData.class);
```

And names for target objects is:

```
private CurrencyData currencyData;
private UserData data;
private New newz;
```

Somebody can tell me how i can Deserialize this objects?

Comment: Where are those fields declared?

Comment: Are you sure your code even compiles? Show us `ApiResponse` and `UserData`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis those fields are declared in UserData.class as objects. This objects already have getters and setters for any String and int values.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis code compiles correctly but Objects "currencyData", "data" and "new" are null

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i cannot correctly to declare Object with name "new" because it name is not correct for java.

Comment: please add the data model describing the response object and the sub objects.

Comment: I don't believe `ApiResponse<UserData> response = new Gson().fromJson(json, UserData.class);` compiles. In any case. Your JSON doesn't match your POJO structure.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private CurrencyData currencyData;
private UserData data;
@SerializedName("new")
private New newz;
```

Comment: can you share your model structure and ApiResponse classes

Comment: it's just generic class for sending in response listener interface. public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

Comment: logcat says NPE on object New and values into this object. Nothing else